# ANT Adobe Air ANE build Android Cannot access android.app.Activity

Tags: android, ant, air, air-native-extension

Im trying to compile an adobe Air ANE file but I keep on getting this error im unsure how to resolve:

```
[javac] /Users/feli/Desktop/Flurry Analytics/android/src/com/sticksports/nativeExtensions/flurry/FlurryEndSession.java:18: cannot access android.app.Activity
[javac] class file for android.app.Activity not found
[javac]             FlurryAgent.onEndSession( context.getActivity() );
```

the build.xml is calling android like this

```
<javac srcdir="../android/src" destdir="../android/temp/classes" includeantruntime="false">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="/Users/feli/Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130219/sdk/platforms/android-17/android.jar"/>
            <pathelement location="../android/libs/FlashRuntimeExtensions.jar"/>
            <pathelement location="../android/libs/FlurryAgent.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </javac>
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

silly mistake I had on my path! its solved now :)
thanks

Edit: 
Silly mistake is: There was a typo on the path "/Users/feli/Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130219/sdk/platforms/android-17/android.jar" once I fixed the path, ANT built the project successfully.

Comment: @briandfoy - this isn't a "thank you" answer, it's the OP answering their own question.

Comment: @Felipe - can you expand on your answer, so that others may benefit from it?